Add Staging Ground activity to activity tab in user profile
This would include

review actions
revisions
comments

And make this visible for any acting-user A to any meta-reviewing-user B with access to SG. I.e. let me audit specific other users' reviews.
Okay I missed in the announcement that comments and revisions are status-planned, but it doesn't mention review actions.

Post about this in the beta team ([status-planned]): https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/staging-ground-testing/q/123/14

I know this has been privately marked as status-planned but we now have multiple requests for this so I'm escalating this post separately. Also closing the loop in the public now that we're out of the private beta phase also has value even if it's just to pop here with an update on timeline or an answer when it finally completes.
